# Date Comparison in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to compare two columns containing date values and find the difference between the 2 dates.

Out of the 2 columns one is of `datetime` type however another is an `object` type. W
hen trying to convert the object type to datetime using:

```
final['Valid to']=pd.to_datetime(final['Valid to'])
```

I am getting an error:

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31
>   00:00:00

How to convert the column of object type to datetime so that i can compare and get the required result?

Comment: This should be the correct way. But to really have look at the problem you should post a sample of your data, e.g. `final.head()`. Otherwise people can just guess...

Comment: the data is in the following format: 2017-03-03 00:00:00

Comment: final['Valid to'].head()
Out[78]: 
    2017-03-03 00:00:00
    2016-01-23 00:00:00
    2017-05-19 00:00:00
    2013-06-27 00:00:00
   2015-01-18 00:00:00
Name: Valid to, dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use format parameter to provide the correct format of the string so that to_datetime can understand what type of string it is converting into datetime object

in your case it would be like

`pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

please post the sample data for the correct answer as someone have already written in the comment, that would be helpful.

Comment: the data for the 2 columns i want to compare are:  final['Termination Date'].head()
Out[77]: 
0   2017-03-03
1   2017-05-31
2   2017-05-19
3   2017-05-02
4   2017-06-29
Name: Termination Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]   and final['Valid to'].head()
Out[78]: 
0    2017-03-03 00:00:00
1    2016-01-23 00:00:00
2    2017-05-19 00:00:00
3    2013-06-27 00:00:00
4    2015-01-18 00:00:00
Name: Valid to, dtype: object

Comment: when i try to format the column gets converted,  but when i try final.dtypes again, it shows as object type

Comment: Thanks a lot..i was able to fix it